# logging controller methods from one point Swift

Tags: swift, logging

I want to log all controller methods calls including methodname, methodparams and dont want to write a log  to each method. It should handle from one point. is it possible to write interceptor or aspect in swift?

ex. 2016-05-05 09:47:33.927 xxx[58787:27517992] init() method called with params ["xxx", "yyy"]

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is _not_ possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Does Swift support aspect oriented programming?](/q/24136535/90527)"

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift >=2.2**:

You can try to do:

```
 print("\(NSDate()) \(#file) \(#line) \(#function) in \(self.dynamicType)")
```

You can use a global method like this:

```
func VerboseLog<T>(object: T, filename: String = #file, line: Int = #line, funcname: String = #function) {
    print("\(NSDate()) \(filename) \(line) \(funcname) in \(object.dynamicType)")
}
```

> **More information**:

`#file` - String - The name of the file in which it appears.

`#line` - Int - The line number on which it appears.

`#column` - Int - The column number in which it begins.

`#function` - String - The name of the declaration in which it appears.

[Apple official source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html).

About aspect oriented programming as you ask, unfortunately Swift dont has now a runtime support. You must refer to obj-c bridging.

There is an interesting library called [MOAspect](https://github.com/MO-AI/MOAspects) that can be useful if you want to use this kind of approach:

```
MOAspects.hookClassMethodForClass(UIScreen.self, selector:"mainScreen", position:.Before) {
    NSLog("hooked screen!")
}

UIScreen.mainScreen() // -> hooked screen!
```

Comment: Its ok for logging, but how can i intercept each method calls and log it there, like @Before pointcut in AOP.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can also subclassing your controllers with a custom class and add this log in an ovveride method like viewDidLoad

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano, this is not what the OP asked for, and it is explicitly mentioned in the second line of the original question. To be more specific, it is only a part of the answer, and not the most important part.

Comment: Ok I've update the answer. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: I read about swizzling. I will try that firstly. If not able to do then i will try obj-c bridging.